# Fetching the image data(stored as binary) from Hive with JDBC

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am fetching image data from a hive which is stored as binary data like
by using an `InputStream` object. The problem is when I am trying to encode the image, it's getting encoded but again when I am trying to decode the same encoded image it's throwing an error.

My program looks like this:

```
File file=new File("path");
                    java.io.InputStream in = rs1.getBinaryStream("entity_image");
OutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
int c=0;
while((c=in.read())>-1)
{
 //System.out.println(c);
   f.write(c);
}
byte[] imageBytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
                    in.read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
                    in.close();
                    String imageStr = encodeImage(imageBytes);//method that returns the encoded base64 String.
 byte[] imageByteArray = decodeImage(imgstring);//method returning byte []
    f.write(imageByteArray);//writing the decoded image to the file
```

1. The new image file is saying that it contains error while opening?
2. Are there any other ways available for fetching the image data from the hive?
   I checked with `getbytes()` method, but it says the method is not supported.

Comment: Please show the stacktrace / error you see

Comment: i am not getting error while running the program but while opnening the image i am getting error like:Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00

Comment: but finally i got the solution Thanks